# Running flutter while offline - stuck on Resolving Dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, dependencies

I'm trying to set up Flutter on a PC without internet connection.
I get stuck on "Resolving Dependencies" when trying to run an app (on a physical Nexus 5), and after some time I get a "Build failed with an exception" and a lot of failed download messages.

I installed the required software (inc. VSCode) as well as copied the flutter and gradle folders from my other PC where I normally use Flutter to develop.
Flutter doctor says I'm all good. I created the app offline using "flutter create --offline name_of_app".
This happens even if I try to run the app using Android Studio with gradle set to offline work and a path is directing to a full gradle distribution.

The error is:

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\name_of_app\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not download gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.jar'.
         > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.jar'.
```

And it continues to mention other file names as well.

What am I missing? I can run the app on my other PC when I disconnect it from the internet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just run it once with online access and when it downloads `gradle-3.2.1.jar` (and other needed stuff) you can later on run it offline

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot connect that PC to the internet at all. All the necessary files are already on that PC since I copied the .gradle folder from my other (connected) PC to that one, but for whatever reason the disconnected PC doesn't use those cached files.

Comment: so how did you install `flutter` at all as it needs internet access during installation?

Comment: I downloaded in advance and installed the required software (inc. VSCode) as well as copied the flutter and gradle folders from my other PC where I normally use Flutter to develop. Flutter doctor says I'm all good. I created the app offline using "flutter create --offline name_of_app".

Comment: use `google("copy gradle cache")` then  - it returns for example: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-copy-gradle-caches-to-another-offline-machine/23413

Comment: Thanks, I reviewed most of the links and understood the issue. Appreciate your help!

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 3):

As a beginner both in programming and in flutter I commit this answer with caveats. It worked on my machine (a Lenovo laptop), on Manjaro Linux.

First problem I had encountered during the compilation phase was the -beta01 problem. The gradle offline plugin available for download from android studio site has currently version number 3.5.0-beta01. By some automatism 'flutter create --offline' sets the dependency to gradle:3.5.0 in the global build.gradle file. I solved that part of the problem by replacing 3.5.0 with 3.5.0-beta01.

Second problem was a number of missing dependencies compiler complained about. I downloaded them all and put them in the gradle plugin folder (in Linux it's /home/username/.android/manual-offline-m2/android-gradle-plugin-3.5.0-beta01/ - the recommended path from the Android studio configuration walk-through). They were mostly gradle and kotlin related.

When I resolved the second order dependencies the work was done. The base flutter app compiled with no errors , with all the offline settings (online repositories' paths in global build.gradle commented out, internet disconnected).

For offline use, which is solely for learning purposes, I plan not to update flutter channels, nor the maven and gradle plugin, being that the only reason one would use a computer with no internet access for flutter is for learning in the beginner's phase ... Up in the mountains of Croatia... At least that's where I plan to use it :D